# How can I debug something I cant often re-create?

Tags: swift, debugging, ios9, xcode7

So I have had this bug for a long time that I have been unable to track down.  The problem is I cant recreate it often.

So far I have tracked the bug down to a specific process that basically goes like this.

Their are three simultaneous processes that go on that take different lengths of time. After each process is done it sets a boolean "key" to true, and then triggers a function that checks if all "keys" are in place.  Basically once the last "key" is in it will actually start to do things.

Somewhere in the key setting process, or earlier, or even possibly after it crashes.  Unfortunately it leaves a really cryptic error message, and when it crashes in Xcode it is "EXEC BAD ACESS" and thus just puts a breakpoint in the app delegate declaration.

I am sure I can easily fix this bug, I just dont know enough on how to fix this. Thankfully I have fabric which allows me to print to a text file that I can see when a user crashes.  Each update I add new data to it (at the cost of a tad bit of latency) in order to better understand how it happened.  Each new crash gets me closer. Unfortunately though I have slow adoption rates to new versions and the crashes just keep building up!  I still dont know why.

Unfortunately because this crash only happens once in a blue moon (atleast on my device) on my device. And because of the low new version updates I have to collect the data myself.  Which is really hard!

I have tried tons of methods of trying to get things to go wrong, or making the process that caused it happen rapidly, or even having auto pressing buttons.  Still i cant get it to crash again!  And when it does all I can do to track down the bug is add more println calls so I can see what is going on.

The freaky thing is for all I know I could have already fixed it because I usually try new tweaks ect.  But I won't know because it won't consistently crashes. Honestly i'm fairly sure I fixed it (or at least took down the chances of it happening).

What would you do in a situation like this?

Comment: Being able to reproduce is pretty important — have you tried adding artificial/random delays, or making the processes happen faster & more frequently, to trigger the crash more easily? Try enabling zombies. Also make sure to use some sort of synchronization between threads.

Comment: Try printing a message to console for every block of code (5 or so lines, the less lines the better), then see which message is the last to be printed - this should tell you where the error occurred.

Comment: @jtbandes what would synchronization between threads look like? Cause that could be one of the problems.  Because the code called to check if all three keys are in place is just in the SKScene.  However one of the codes will call it from a preloadTextureWithCompletionHandler's handler, perhaps causing it to call the 3 key check on a 2nd thread instead of the first? I have seen time where printing calls get merged.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091

Comment: I would recommend dispatch_group or NSOperationQueue for this particular case.

Comment: i second what @jtbandes said, I would look into using dispatch_groups for this kind of thing

Answer (score 0):

This sound like a [race condition](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Conceptual/SecureCodingGuide/Articles/RaceConditions.html)

I would use [NSOperationQueue](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/) to make sure that all he tasks are done in order and that all are actually completed before the final one is performed.